# Dart Flutter: The default value of an optional parameter must be constant when setting a default value to class constructor

Tags: class, flutter, dart, default-value

I created a class `JobBloc` that contains a number of properties one of which is another class object `JobModel`, I want to assign a default value to each of these properties, it works fine except for the `JobModel` property:

```
class JobBloc with JobModelFormValidator {
  final JobModel jobModel;
  final bool isValid;
  final bool showErrorMessage;
  final String name;
  final double ratePerHour;
  final bool enableForm;
  final bool showIcon;

  JobBloc({
    // The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.
    this.jobModel = JobModel(name: 'EMPTY', ratePerHour: 0.01), // <= the error stems from this line
    this.isValid = false,
    this.showErrorMessage = false,
    this.name = 'EMPTY',
    this.enableForm = true,
    this.ratePerHour = 0.01,
    this.showIcon = false,
    });
}
```

How can I assign a default value to my `jobModel` property?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't initialize an object in a class model.

Try:

```
class JobBloc with JobModelFormValidator {
  final JobModel jobModel;
  final bool isValid;
  final bool showErrorMessage;
  final String name;
  final double ratePerHour;
  final bool enableForm;
  final bool showIcon;

  JobBloc({
    this.isValid = false,
    this.showErrorMessage = false,
    this.name = 'EMPTY',
    this.enableForm = true,
    this.ratePerHour = 0.01,
    this.showIcon = false,
    }) : jobModel = JobModel(name: 'EMPTY', ratePerHour: 0.01);
}
```

Or update the jobModel class

```
class JobModel {
  final String name;
  final double ratePerHour;

  JobModel({
    this.name = 'EMPTY',
    this.ratePerHour = 0.01,
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you, I am confused as there are too many ways to write the same thing. 
The first solution worked, could you explain the first syntax? What is the meaning and use of the colon `:` here?

Comment: The colon after a constructor is called an initializer list in Flutter.
It allows you to initialize fields of your class, make assertions and call the super constructor. If you want to learn more: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list

Answer (score 1):

Try this may be ?

```
class JobBloc with JobModelFormValidator {
  final JobModel jobModel;
  final bool isValid;
  final bool showErrorMessage;
  final String name;
  final double ratePerHour;
  final bool enableForm;
  final bool showIcon;

  JobBloc({
    this.jobModel = const JobModel(name: 'EMPTY', ratePerHour: 0.01),
    this.isValid = false,
    this.showErrorMessage = false,
    this.name = 'EMPTY',
    this.enableForm = true,
    this.ratePerHour = 0.01,
    this.showIcon = false,
    });
}
```